# TSQL help calculate percentage

Tags: t-sql

I wonder how to do this with a variable:

```
SELECT  Count(distinct UserIP) 
FROM VisitorIP 
G0

SELECT Country, Count(distinct UserIP) Visitors, Count(distinct UserIP) * 100 / 2865 Pct 
FROM VisitorIP group by country order by Visitors desc
```

Now I want to replace 2865 by the count(distinct UserIP) above.

There is a say: In IT, better one who knows than 10 who search!

Any clue welcome...
Happy New Year to all geeks out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a variable:

```
DECLARE @userip_count int

SELECT @userip_count = Count(distinct UserIP) 
FROM VisitorIP 

SELECT Country, Count(distinct UserIP) Visitors, Count(distinct UserIP) * 100 / @userip_count Pct 
FROM VisitorIP group by country order by Visitors desc
GO
```

Moving `GO` is essential here, in order for the variable to remain in scope for use in the second query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Country, 
Count(distinct UserIP) Visitors, 
round(Count(distinct UserIP) / 
              (SELECT  Count(distinct UserIP) 
              FROM VisitorIP) * 100,2) Pct 
FROM VisitorIP 
group by country 
order by Visitors desc
```